# Android facebook SDK 3.0 post using access token from webservice

Tags: android, facebook

I am creating an app for a site. the site has the option to sync there account with the their facebook account. when the person log in the Android app the access token of the user is recived through webservice. 
how can i use this access token to open a sesson and post to facebook using facebook SDK 3.0?

Answer (score 0):

There is method for opening session with accessToken->

session.openActiveSessionWithAccessToken(context, accessToken, callback);

It will return session object, then you can use returned Session object to do further operations.